# Know when phone enters building on android device

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I was wondering if there is a way for me to detect if the users device is being "obstructed" by a building or roof of some sort. Im developing a very precise location based app and its KEY that my users get alerted if something is wrong with there GPS or something is getting in the way. Physical object.

EDIT: The app ive created strictly takes snapshots too its not something thats constantly going. Just a quick snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly.  You can try calling LocationManager.getGpsStatus and iterating over the list of satelites every so often and looking for a jump in signal to noise ratio since the last reading.  Getting a working algorithm is going to take a good amount of work and testing on a variety of devices with different GPS chips.

Comment: So something that once i accomplish it would make a great open source project on github and hopefully would grab a lot of contributers if done right... sounds like i got a mission and a half ahead of me. I figured this would be my solution to create an extension of android location. We did the same for the iOS version but didnt want to have to for Android. I'll wait until other answers are posted to see if anyone else has any other thoughts before accepting your answer.

Comment: It may be that someone has already done it.  Its impossible to keep up with open source speed and I don't even try-  I look up libraries when I need them :)  It would definitely be cool to have though-  I think we can do a lot of interesting things with phones that are aware of their context-  where they are, how fast they're moving, figuring out what the owner is doing.  This could definitely have a place, knowing where you are.  I could put it into my parking detection app to tell when you're entering a parking lot (or to know you did so recently so I need to take an older location)

Comment: What really makes this a challenge is the way that GPS works in general. It works based on triangulation from multiple satellites. For instance a device could essentially be connected to 16 satellites at one moment and then minutes later only have connection with 4 satellites. Determining what is blocking them is a challenge because it could be any number of things from any range.

Comment: @aaron russell any success with finding a solution or open source work group?

Comment: No success yet, however im not working with Java anymore, i have switched to the new Intel XDK NEW using Cordova API.